# How to embed a OCaml top level like try.ocamlpro.com

Tags: ocaml

on http://try.ocamlpro.com/, there is a top level window.

How was it implemented?

How can I also embed one for my website?

Comment: If you View/Source or Inspect Element from Chrome, you'll see that it is just a textarea.  The OCaml intepreter is in a Javascript file called `try-ocaml.js`, which contains about 140,000 lines of Javascript code (un-minified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for tryocaml is on github [here](https://github.com/OCamlPro/tryocaml), it is a patched ocaml standard interpreter compiled with [js_of_ocaml](http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/).

If you're familiar with OCaml and js_of_ocaml, patching it to your needs should be quite easy.